# Sticking the content of .load into a variable

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-load

Is it possible to use jQuery's [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and stick the loaded content into a variable so I can use the variable and append it to something else later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but this is unnecessary. Use the [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method to directly access the response instead.

```
$.get("foo.php",function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

If you want to do both, (i.e. load the response into a div and use the returned data), you can use the callback on the `$.load` method similarly.

Answer (score 4):

According [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

So you can create function to save your response:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function(responseText, textStatus, request) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

Other approach is to use [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert(data);
});

$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(selector).load(url);
```

Is just a shorthand for:

```
$.get(url, data, function(response) {
    $(selecton).replaceWith(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in AJAX

```
$.post(yourfile,function(response) {
     //div hidden with the html of your page
      $("#hiddendiv").html(response);
});
```

OR with get

```
$.get(yourfile,function(response) {
     //div hidden with the html of your page
      $("#hiddendiv").html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case use GET, POST or AJAX method of jquery.
`.load` method of jquery internally uses asynchronous http request only and so all above mentioned methods.